# How to convert request object to model Spring Webflux

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflux, project-reactor

My RestController has a request object (DTO) and I need to convert to my model object (MongoDB Document), but what is the correct way to do this conversion with Spring Webflux and not block I/O?

I thought some things:

My DTO as a Publisher (Mono) and then I convert to my model and call my business layer:

```
@PostMapping("/persons")
public Mono<ResponseEntity<Void>> save(@RequestBody Mono<PersonRequest> request) {
    return request.map(r -> Person.builder()
                        .id(r.getId())
                        .name(r.getName())
                        .build())
            .flatMap(personService::save)
            .map(p -> ResponseEntity.ok().build());
}
```

Or my DTO don't need to be a Publisher?

```
@PostMapping("/persons")
public Mono<ResponseEntity<Void>> save(@RequestBody PersonRequest request) {
    return personService.save(Person.builder()
                        .id(request.getId())
                        .name(request.getName())
                        .build())
            .map(p -> ResponseEntity.ok().build());
}
```

Comment: If you are using classic annotated controller just use straight DTO. No need to over complicate things. Handler methods generally use ServerRequest.monoToClass etc

Answer (score 2):

If you use Functional Style rather than annotations then ServerRequest provide methods like bodyToFlux(Person.class) that can be used and are totally non-blocking.

If you use annotation style than do like below:

```
 @PostMapping("/person")
    Mono<Void> create(@RequestBody Publisher<Person> personStream) {
            return this.repository.save(personStream).then();
    }
```

This is because, as you said, if you don't use Publisher then the conversion to Person will be blocking. 
Refer section 2.1.1 at https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.0.0.RC4/spring-framework-reference/reactive-web.html

Comment: Ok, but if I need to receive a DTO like PersonRequest and parse to Person, should I parse directly without be a Mono or should I transform the DTO to a Mono and then parse to my model class? I would like to know if a don't transform my DTO as a Mono I will block my I/O and not be reactive.

Comment: I have edited the response... you are right that if you don't use a Publisher then the conversion will be blocking.